# SQL record selection using if then

Tags: sql

I'm using a report generator (Viewpoint). I've generated a report and corresponding prompt to that has user enter a Branch (&SLST00) and a date range (&FRDAT and &TODAT).

Below is the SQL that the report writer generates. It works fine as long as the user enters a Branch.

What change would I have to make so that if the user does not enter a Branch code, ALL Branch order data within the date range would be included in the listing?

```
SELECT slst00.orderh COLHDG("Controlling" "Branch"), 
       driv00.orderh, 
       name10.driver, 
       pro#00.orderh EDTCDE(Z), 
       sufx00.orderh EDTCDE(J), 
       osta00.orderh COLHDG("Order" "Status"), 
       tchg00.orderh EDTCDE(J), 
       dlcd00.orderh, 
       sfdt00.orderh COLHDG("Ship" "Date") EDTCDE(W), 
       trip00.orderh COLHDG("Trip #") EDTCDE(L)

FROM  tgilibdb/orderh,tgilibdb/driver
INNER JOIN driv00.orderh=driv10.driver
WHERE ORDERH.SLST00=&SLST00 
AND   ORDERH.STDT00 BETWEEN &FRDAT AND &TODAT
ORDER BY slst00 ASC,driv00 ASC
```

Comment: Does something in that code actually represent something called a "branch"?

Comment: @WayneC - is this some sort of IBM DB2 or similar?  Those EDTCDE and COLHDG keywords aren't exactly standard SQL.

Comment: More information about this query and how the data for Branch is used - is Branch a placeholder? - would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on your server, but I've used something like this on SQL before. You'll have to adjust `&SLST00=""` according to what the default Branch value is.

```
SELECT slst00.orderh COLHDG("Controlling" "Branch"), 
       driv00.orderh, 
       name10.driver, 
       pro#00.orderh EDTCDE(Z), 
       sufx00.orderh EDTCDE(J), 
       osta00.orderh COLHDG("Order" "Status"), 
       tchg00.orderh EDTCDE(J), 
       dlcd00.orderh, 
       sfdt00.orderh COLHDG("Ship" "Date") EDTCDE(W), 
       trip00.orderh COLHDG("Trip #") EDTCDE(L)

FROM  tgilibdb/orderh,tgilibdb/driver
INNER JOIN driv00.orderh=driv10.driver
WHERE (&SLST00="" OR ORDERH.SLST00=&SLST00)
AND   ORDERH.STDT00 BETWEEN &FRDAT AND &TODAT
ORDER BY slst00 ASC,driv00 ASC
```